# FB API add image to facebook page album

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to figure out if it's possible to add an image to Facebook page album if you're not an administrator. I have an app that enables curently only admins to do this. That's easy because they have an access_token in /me/accounts. Is there a way to generate a public access_token for all users, that lasts for 2 weeks or maybe more? I need them to add the photos in a specific way, an the app makes it easier.